# How can I find the *points* of intersection of two arbitrary squares?

Tags: geometry, polygons, computational-geometry, rectangles

I've seen innumerable answers involving collision/overlap/etc., also areas of same.
I've seen some Q/As around axis-aligned rects or polys, or intersections of lines/vectors with arbitrary polys, or various combinations of those.

I need:

1. The points of intersection of exactly two squares of arbitrary size (but let's say within the same order of magnitude, probably in most cases much closer in size than that) and orientation
2. Needs to be algorithmic. I do want to be able to code the answer, so solutions involving doing geometry by hand won't really help

My math skills are pretty weak, so the chances of me figuring this out on my own are pretty slim...

What I've thought of trying is something like (pseudocode)

```
if squares overlap:
    check each pair of sides for intersect point using line-intersection formula  # This means at most 16 checks (unless I'm wrong and it's more :) )
```

which feels *worse* than brute-force (if that's even a thing)

Edit: So of course, *now* SE chooses to suggest [how-to-find-points-of-intersection-of-two-rectangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4370788/how-to-find-points-of-intersection-of-two-rectangles)... again, though, it looks like the rects in question are expected to be axis-aligned

Comment: What’s wrong with “each pair of sides” after all?

Comment: It seems horribly inefficient at the least... I'm hoping that there's a better answer?

Comment: "*It seems horribly inefficient*" $\;-\;$ Two squares can intersect in $8$ points on $8$ pairs of sides out of the total $16$. Checking all $16$ combinations may not be optimal, but it's not "*horribly*" inefficient either. That said, the question may be better suited for [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) since it's more about implementation than math.

Comment: You might be interested in a Google Answers post [Q: Determining whether two rotated rectangles intersect](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/531318.html) where I wrote some C# code for *detecting* intersections between two rotated rectangles.  While there are some mathematical aspects of the problem, you seem to want to write a software implementation yourself, so StackOverflow seems more apt.  Note that the intersection of two bounded convex regions (as here) is either empty or itself a bounded convex region.  A polygon formed by the intersection has at most 8 sides.

Comment: Do you know the $x$- and $y$- coordinates of the eight vertices of the two squares?

Comment: *Do you know the x- and y- coordinates of the eight vertices of the two squares?* -
Not outright, but I'm planning to implement storing them in the data structure I'm using to hold the other data for the squares.

Comment: You can reduce the number of checks by using the fact that at most two points of intersections are possible for each side so if you already found two, there is no need to check further. Another improvement: if a side square A intersects a side of the square B, the opposite side of the square A cannot intersect the same side of the square B.